# pick up the last id from other table within single action

Tags: laravel

I am working with a purchase ordering app. I have two tables, the orders table, and order_items. I would like to order_items to grab the id of orders which is in a single action. apology if I wasn't able to explain it clearly. here's my store function.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $orders = $request->only(
        'user_id',
        'status_id',
        'currency_id',
        'company_id',
        'purchase_no',
        'notes',
        'delivery_date',
        'publish'
    );
    $orders['grandtotal'] = (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->grandtotal);
    $orders = Orders::create($orders);

    $input = $request->all();
    for($i=0; $i<= count($input['quantity']); $i++) {
    if(empty($input['quantity'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['quantity'][$i])) continue;
        $items = [ 
            'order_id' => $input['order_id'][$i],
            'product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i],
            'product_code' => $input['product_code'][$i],
            'product_name' => $input['product_name'][$i],
            'cost' => $input['cost'][$i],
            'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i]),
            'total_cost' => (float) str_replace(',', '', $input['total_cost'][$i]),
        ];
        Orderitems::create($items);
    }

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

what should I do to achieve this process? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain `order_items to grab the id of orders which is in single action` a little more please?

Comment: from where ? I couldn't understand well

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. What I am trying to say is that, in that single process which is posting a purchase order, i will store the data in two tables ORDERS and ORDER_ITEMS. what I want is to grab the id from ORDERS which is just created and grab by ORDER_ITEMS table column oders_id. but that should happen in that single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace  $input['order_id'][$i] with $orders->id, It might help you.

```
    $items = [ 
        'order_id' => $orders->id,
        'product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i],
        'product_code' => $input['product_code'][$i],
        'product_name' => $input['product_name'][$i],
        'cost' => $input['cost'][$i],
        'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i]),
        'total_cost' => (float) str_replace(',', '', $input['total_cost'][$i]),
    ];
```